# Can't drop GROUP or BUTTON onto Watchkit App's Storyboard "Hosting Controller"?

Tags: xcode, xcode11, watchos

TL;DR - when I drag a Group onto the Watch in storyboard, it vanishes, nothing shows, no sign. Huh?

Newbie on Xcode11 and WatchOS6. I created a new Watch App, went down to the WatchKit App, clicked on the Interface.storyboard, then tried to add a Group onto the watch (which says "Hosting Controller").  (I'm following around with a youtube swift tutorial).  I can click +, find Group, but when I drag and release onto the Watch, it simply vanishes - nothing else seems to happen.

I'm unsure why it's not adding it, and not sure where to go from here.

[image: GIF of what I'm talking about]

Comment: Okay, I figured out what's happening, but not what to do next (looking for demos now). Xcode 11 adds a new "SwiftUI" user interface option when you create a project (where it would normally be Storyboard) and it behaves differently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This one is going to catch a few people out I guess. Especially those new to Xcode trying to follow existing tutorials.

When creating a project make sure you select *Storyboard* under **User Interface**

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful!